# SQL Join on Time stamp with 1 minute varrience. DATEDIFF?

Tags: sql, left-join, datediff

Our organization has a pair of systems joined by an interface.  System A is used to create records (about 1000/day), System B is used to display them (from system A and other sources).  We have discovered that some records from A are not crossing the interface properly to B.  I am trying to Identify which records have not crossed.  I have the Table of Records from A and a table of the records in B.  I initially joined them using an Account number field, a Date field and separate time field.  We then discovered that for 8-10% of the records, the time stamp in table B is one min. different than the corresponding record in Table A. (it happens in the interface, we're not sure why)

By using the Description field that is in Table B but not A, I could find those records in TableA that did not link with a record in B, therefore displaying those items that did not cross in the interface.

I have attempted to use datediff in the join statement, trying to allow a variance of 1 min, and still get a join.  Inspecting the results have shown that the results are joining records with vastly different time fields.  The statement I have attempted to use is below:

```
select TableA.NoteDate, TableB.ReportDT, TableA.NoteTime, TableB.ReportTime, 
TableA.UserName,     TableA.AcctNum, TableB.AccountNumber, TableA.NoteID, 
TableB.Description
from TableA

left join TableB on 

( 
TableA.NoteDate =  TableB.ReportDT and 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TableA.NoteTime, TableB.ReportTime) <= 1 and 
TableA.AcctNum = TableB.AccountNumber
)

WHERE
TableA.txtNoteDate >= '2013-09-01' AND
TableA.txtNoteDate <= '2013-09-30' And 
Description is NULL

ORDER BY Description
```

Am I on the right track, or should I be approaching this from a different direction altogether?

Comment: You are on the right track.  You have to qualify description in your where and order by clauses though.

Comment: "Description" is a field - it's in the select portion - and the query runs as it is, but the results show records being joined that have vastly different times, rather than the 1 minute varience I want to allow...